# Reading a web page in Java IOException Premature EOF

Tags: java, io, eof, urlconnection

I am frequently getting a 'Premature EOF' Exception when reading a web page.

The following is the StackTrace

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:556)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:600)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:687)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2968)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at Utilities.getPage(Utilities.java:24)  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    at TalkPage.<init>(TalkPage.java:15)
    at Updater.run(Updater.java:65)
```

Following is the getPage() method

```
public static String getPage(String urlString) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {  // LINE 24
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

What is a permature EOFException and why is it occuring in this particular case and how can it be avoided?

Some other information: The size of the page being read is around 20 KB and I'm reading many such pages in my program ( around 20 000 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be because you are reading the content line by line and for the last line the file may be missing a return, to signal the end of line. Replace your while with this:

```
int BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE]; // or some other size, 
int charsRead = 0;
while ( (charsRead  = rd.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
  sb.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
}
```

Comment: and for the last line the file may be missing a return ::: When I am reading the same web page a second time, I am not getting any error. So, I think that might not be the problem. And, can you answer the other part of the question also : What is a permature EOFException

Comment: The "permature EOFException" is happening when you are expecting something, like here a line termination, but there is none in the stream.

Comment: @Ranjith-SR2GF Have you tried my fix? It should work each time. The issue for you it may be that the server is not pushing that last end line character.

Comment: For now, I have finished downloading the required web pages. I shall try it the next time I need to do a similar job. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @brgr Not sure why your edit was rejected, it was a good edit, thanks.

Comment: @dan I have very similar code and this error still occurs.

Comment: @momo You should submit a new question with your code. This way we will be able to discuss what is different.

Comment: why this will not cause Premature EOF , Premature EOF comes when no signal is returned for an end of stream and still the bytes/characters stops coming , how calling rd.read() will help here , Might be solution is correct but if you can give an explanation, will be much helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This could be because the server is closing the connection.  I have experienced the exact same issue when I had a piece of code which opened a connection, did some other processing, and only *then* tried to download the contents of the input stream - by the time it to the stream after spending a few seconds on other processing, the server had apparently closed the connection, resulting in IOException: Premature EOF.  The solution was to be careful to always immediately handle the contents of the stream - otherwise, you are leaving an HTTP connection open and idle, and eventually the server on the other end of the line will hang up on you.

Comment: This could also be because the server is only sending headers and no body as response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use APACHE `commons io FileUtils.copyURLToFile` method

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: I want to get the contents of the URL into a String and I do not want to write it to a file and read it back again.

Comment: It would take another LOC to read it from file to String... http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

Comment: Why do you think this is better?

Comment: @Aitul Above mentioned links are not working please update.

Comment: `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(InputStream, Charset)` can be used to read from a URL into a String without any temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the buffer size to 1. This slightly helps and if you implement a try logic around it, then it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try{                
            URL url = new URL(address);

            InputStream is = url.openStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String str;

            while((str = in.readLine()) != null){

                sb.append(str);

                sb.append("\n");
            }

            in.close();
            isr.close();
            is.close();

            return sb.toString();

         }catch(Exception e){

             //OMG....
         }
```