# inconsistent byte array read from socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I have two applications running on two different servers.
One application connects to the other one by socket connection and through that socket it sends data. The receiving application reads that data and does something with it.
The sending application uses the next piece of code to do it:

```
out.write(int2ByteArray(size));
out.flush();
Thread.sleep(5);
out.write(full_packet);
out.flush();
```

`full_packet` is a byte array with the dimension of `size * 53` and `int2ByteArray()` method looks like this :

```
private static  byte[] int2ByteArray(int myInt){
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(myInt).array();
}
```

So basically, I send the size of my data packet before I send the actual data.

The receiving application reads the data using the next piece of code:

```
while (running){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // read input data
    byte[] first_drop = new byte[4];
    in.read(first_drop);
    int size = byteArray2Int(first_drop);
    byte[] packet  = new byte [size * packet_size];
    Thread.sleep(5);
    in.read(packet);

    // do some thing with packet

    // go to sleep
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep(1000 - (endTime-startTime));
 }
```

`packet_size` equal 53. `byteArray2Int()` method looks like this:

```
private int byteArray2Int(byte[] bArr){
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bArr).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
    }
```

`in` is of type `DataInputStream`.

The problem starts now. When I run both applications on my laptop everything is fine and all data comes through the way it was sent. I run several threads of the sending application, sending several sizes of data streams. 
However, when run it on the servers, if the data is to big it does not come through as it should. 
If I am trying to send packets that are 5300 bytes long then it is fine. If I am sending packets that are 15900 bytes long and even bigger, at some point the reading application does not read the data packet properly and the next time it reads the 4 bytes of the size it receives some weird number and it jams the application.
Same thing happens when I try to run several threads, each one send different data with a different size.

Can anyone point out the problem in the process? How can I fix it? Any suggestions?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `out.flush()` calls actually send the packet over the network.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm for one reason why the small packet could be held.  As implied by @glee8e's answer, a TCP stream is just that, a stream.  You can not rely on packet boundaries being preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStream` doesn't always read all bytes arrived into your byte array. When the packet is small enough, the underlying `InputStream` implementation may return the whole packet, but, if it grows larger, as  in your later experiments, it may not read them in a whole because its buffer can't hold that much of data, as mentioned by @ycesar. One way is to increase buffer size, but it is just hiding the problem. To really solve the problem, you need to check if the return value of `InputStream.read()` match the expected packet size.

There are convenience methods like `IOUtils.read()` in apache commons-io. You can make use of it or modify it for your own purpose as long as the license is followed. It looks like this:

```
public static final int EOF = -1;

public static int read(final InputStream input, final byte[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
        throws IOException {
    if (length < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length must not be negative: " + length);
    }
    int remaining = length;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        final int location = length - remaining;
        final int count = input.read(buffer, offset + location, remaining);
        if (EOF == count) { // EOF
            break;
        }
        remaining -= count;
    }
    return length - remaining;
}
```

Above code is copied from https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/2.5/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#L2901 licensed under [Apache 2.0](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/2.5/LICENSE.txt). No modifications.

Comment: @EJP excuse me, but how to solve a premature EOF? I searched SO and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13210179/5818889) but he didn't explained why his code works. Previously I just use http client libraries and even never used HttpURLConnections by hand.

Comment: *Now that you've posted the value of the EOF variable and made it clear that it's a constant whose value is -1,* this code won't fail if there is a premature EOF.

Comment: :/ It seems that I'm even not qulified for a copycat.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the count returned by `read()`. The simplest way to accomplish this is wih `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but maybe the default socket receive bufer is below expectations. Why don't you try with `setReceiveBufferSize()` function to increase this receive buffer size?

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is just hiding the actual problem, and the receive buffer size isn't intended to be used like this. It is to ensure fast download, not to solve problems like this.

Comment: There is no evidence here that the socket receive buffer is too small, and you haven't identified the real problem.